# Using partitions (window functions) in combination with aggregations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

In MongoDB I have documents like below (I cross the names of calls for confidentiality):

[image]

Now I need to build a query to return results grouped by the name of the call and for each type of call I need to get the number of calls by month, day and hour. Also, in this query I need to indicate a range between two dates (including time).

In SQL server this is done using window functions (partitions) in combination with aggregations but how can I do the same in Mongo?

I am using MongoDB compass as mongo client.

I need to obtain something as below:

```
call name      month    day  hour  #ByMonth  #ByDay   #ByHour
GetEmployee    January  1    14    10         6       1    
GetEnployee    January  1    18    10         6       5
GetEmployee    January  3    12    10         4       4
GetEmployee    March    5    20    8          8       8
GetEmployee    April    12   17    45         35      35
GetEmployee    April    20   10    45         10      10
```

For example, for GetEmployee call the distribution is as below:

- 10 calls done in January
- 8 calls done in March
- 45 calls done in April

For the January, the 10 calls are being distributed as below:

- 6 calls done on 1st January(these 6 calls are distributed as follows: 1 call at 14h and 5 calls at 18h)
- 4 calls done on 3rd January(these 4 calls are all done at 12h)

and so on for the rest of months.

For example, in SQL Server, if I have below table:

```
processName   initDateTime           
processA      2020-06-15 13:31:15.330
processB      2020-06-20 10:00:30.000
processA      2020-06-20 13:31:15.330
...
and so on
```

The SQL query is:

```
select 
    processName,
    month(initDateTime),
    day(initDateTime),
    datepart(hour, initDateTime),
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by processName, year(initDateTime), month(initDateTime)) byMonth,
    sum(count(*)) over(partition by processName, year(initDateTime), month(initDateTime), day(initDateTime)) byDay,
    count(*) byHour
from mytable
group by 
    processName,
    year(initDateTime),
    month(initDateTime),
    day(initDateTime),
    datepart(hour, initDateTime)
```

So How to do the same in Mongo? above processName and initDateTime fields would be "call" and "created" attributes respectively in mongodb.

Comment: Post please your sample as JSON

Comment: @Valijon It is not necessary, only by taking the created and call attributes shown in the image is enough. No need to query any fields in the json. I have updated the post with an example

Comment: You could use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  within [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) and [date expression operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators)

Comment: @styvane could you post an example?